# Redux state not updating array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, state

I have an issue with my redux. This is the first time I am using it in React. I have managed to successfully use it for logging and registering users. However, I have an array of objects created on backend which I am fetching with axios. Axios logs the data and my action creator also logs data in payload. However, it does not update my new state. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong as I tried it exactly the same way as with my login and register states, however these were only boolean values. I have googled and searched for a solution. I tried mapping new array, Object.assign and many others but I can't seem to get it working. Is there any special way on creating new array in state? or can I just assign it action.payload? I appreciate all help

// store.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducer from './reducers/reducer';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(logger, thunk);

export default createStore(reducer, middleware);
```

// rootReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import registerReducer from './registerReducer';
import loginReducer from './loginReducer';
import productsReducer from './products';

export default combineReducers({
  registerReducer,
  loginReducer,
  productsReducer
});
```

// productsReducer // I believe sth must be wrong here

```
import { SHOW_PRODUCTS, SELECT_PRODUCT } from '../actions/products';

const initialState = {
  productsList: []
};

const productsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_PRODUCTS: 
      return {...state, productsList: action.payload}
  }
  return state;
}

export default productsReducer;
```

// actions.js

```
import { SHOW_PRODUCTS, SELECT_PRODUCT } from './constants';

export function showProducts(products) {
  return {
    type: SHOW_PRODUCTS,
    payload: products
  };
}
```

// component.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import ProductsList from './ProductsList';
import { showProducts }  from '../actions/products';


class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getProducts(); 
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>Home Page
        <ProductsList />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    productsList: state.productsReducer.productsList
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getProducts: () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:5000/product/list')
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        dispatch(showProducts(res.data))
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

I am also including a link to an image with my redux logger.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTnYh.png

There's probably a very small, stupid mistake in here as I'm quite new to React and completely new to Redux

Comment: Can you verify if payload have items on productsReducer file?

Comment: have you `console.log()` the action in the `productsReducer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake, and I don't know if you a linter but in `productsReducer.js` you are importing `constants` from `actions` when it should be from `constants`:

```
import { SHOW_PRODUCTS, SELECT_PRODUCT } from '../actions/constants'; // <- from constants instead

const initialState = {
  productsList: []
};

const productsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_PRODUCTS: 
      return {...state, productsList: action.payload}
  }
  return state;
}

export default productsReducer;
```

So your `reducer` shouldn't be actually taken the proper `case` since it is `undefined` and It will so return the initial state.

Comment: I have folder called actions where I also put my constants file, so it is imported correctly. That might be just a bad way of organizing my files, I don't know. if you look at the link I posted https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTnYh.png. the action payload actually returns correct data from the action.payload

Comment: It turns out I was importing it from a wrong path...I wasted all day trying to figure it out...just to notice it the next morning...Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe in `mapStateToProps` you're going to want to do the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        productsList: state.productsList
    };
}
```

To confirm `productsList` being passed through, can you add in a simple loop to the `render` function of `component.js` like below:

```
render() {
    const { productsList } = this.props;
    return(
        <div>
            Home Page
            {productsList.map((product, index) => (
                <div key={index}>{product.PROPERTY_NAME_HERE}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Couple more things, can you elaborate the purpose of ```this.props.getProducts();``` in ```componentWillMount()``` lifecycle event of ```component.js``` and also, you may want to pass ```productsList``` from ```component.js``` render method: ```<ProductList productsList={this.props.productsList} />```

Comment: And finally, can you share code for ```ProductList``` component?

Comment: Yeah...there's nothing there for now...I got stuck with not being able to update my state so as of now I render it in this component. Well, the purpose of `this.props.getProducts()` is to fire this function when component  mounts

Comment: Perhaps you can replace ```ProductList``` component with a simple loop for now to confirm ```productsList``` being retrieved correctly, I've added ```render``` method code as an example

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is redux is returning an empty array in my state

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it with my reducer is

```
import { SHOW_PRODUCTS, SELECT_PRODUCT } from '../actions/products';

const initialState = {
  productsList: []
};

const productsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_PRODUCTS:
      let nextState = {...state};
      nextState.productsList = action.payload
      return nextState;
  }
  return state;
}

export default productsReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.getProducts(); 
}

getProducts() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/product/list')
  .then((res) => {this.props.showProducts(res.data);})
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  showProducts: (data) => {
    dispatch(showProducts(data));
  },
});
```